# An alternative to flex and bison duo?

Tags: compiler-construction

Is there any alternative to flex and bison (lex/yacc) combo? Any other tools that let specify a language grammar in BNF?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of options:

Antlr: http://www.antlr.org/

If you're using C++, Boost::Spirit: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I really like Boost::Spirit's approach to this problem. I won't even have to leave Visual Studio :)

Answer (score 1):

There's [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Two in one, no deps, usable from c or c++, reentrant. I like:
https://www.piumarta.com/software/peg/
Understand the whole thing just reading:
https://www.piumarta.com/software/peg/peg.1.html